# New modem is not connecting to other devices

Tags: wireless-networking, router, security, modem

After installing a new modem, my older devices (Old phones and older computers) don't seem to detect my home internet at all?

I believe the problem has something to do with the security options (or it could be the super new modem), the security options are currently set to - WPA-PSK [TKIP] + WPA2-PSK [AES]

I am using Optus as my carrier and am accessing the security options through NETGEAR Gateway.

The device that I am concerned about is my old HTC HD Desire Phone and an ancient computer that my relative uses.

Any answers pointing to how I could fix the problem would be greatly appreciated. I will add specific details if needed.

Comment: Try setting Channel to 6 or lower in router wireless settings.

Comment: Are you still using the same router? If not, what were you security options set to before? (Your title says "new router" but the body says "new modem". Are you using a combined modem/router?) And what precisely do you mean by saying they don't detect your home Internet? Do you mean they don't detect the wireless network?

Comment: Sorry for the mix up, I've installed a new MODEM.